# How to list all the views and its base object which has unresolved table or other object referece in a paricular database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

I want to list all the views which are made up of base objects. That base object is no longer available.Thanks

Comment: Why did this get  a -1? It seems to be a perfectly valid question to me. I just wish those who downvote would at least have the decency to explain why!

Answer (score 1):

This will return the name of the view(s) and the definition (the CREATE statement) for all views that your table is in.

```
SELECT name, definition
FROM sys.objects     o
JOIN sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE definition LIKE '%<Your table name>%'
```